# How to join three regexp

Tags: javascript

I have a code:

```
this.valor = String(this.valor).replace(/R\$/, '');
this.valor = String(this.valor).replace(/,/g, '');
this.valor = String(this.valor).replace(/\./g, '');
```

Example: put`R$1.000,00` and return `100000`

How to convert in a one line?

Comment: could you also describe what are u trying to achieve? An example of input and expected output for instance

Comment: Something like this `String.replace(/[\r\n\t\.\,]/g, "");`

Comment: @Hitmands update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this, 
however, I don't feel like I should suggest you to go down this path.

Blindly stripping `,` and `.` out might lead to wrong data, 
it seems like you are parsing a currency here and `$1.000,00` doeesn't necessarily equal to `100000`

```js
const sanitize = (string) => string.replace(/[R$.,]/g, '');

console.log(sanitize('R$1.000,00'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use " | " between regular expressions to combine them. As for solution Hitmands answer is recommended

```js
console.log("R$1.000,00".replace(/\.|R\$|\,/g,''))
```